# qt c++ after close window terminating thread / program

Tags: c++, qt

i got this main;

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "tray.h"

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Tray iets;
    app.exec();
 }
```

when i open in tray something like;

```
QFileDialog *dialog = new QFileDialog;
QString dir;

QString test = dialog->getOpenFileName(NULL, NULL, NULL, "Battlefield (*.exe)", NULL, NULL);
for(int i=0; i<test.split("/").size()-1; i++)
    dir+= test.split("/").at(i) + "/";
ui->lePath->setText(test);
```

and i choosed the file its terminating another thread / the program.

how to fi xit?

Comment: Help us to help you: please provide the definition of your `Tray` class.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know (and can't guess) what your `Tray` class is.

However, `Qt` usually terminate the program when the last displayed window (`QWidget` instance) is closed. Unless [specified otherwise](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop).

If `Tray` is not a window (a child class of `QWidget`), then `app.exec()` has no message loop to process and returns immediately, thus terminating the program.

What would you expect/what do you want your program to do at this point exactly ?

---

Not directly related but still important:

Your `main()` function really **should** return an exit status. You can simply change your `main()` so that it looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Tray iets;
    return app.exec(); // app.exec() returns an exit status.
}
```